# Стоит ли покупать Google Nexus 7 со взгляда Android разработчика?

Tags: android

Добрый день, так как занимаюсь изучением Android OS, думаю покупать Google Nexus 7, там и система последней версии и более гладко всё как в обзорах говорят. Что Вы думаете по этому поводу? Очень важно мнение разработчиков под Android!

Comment: ппц, шо значит Google Nexus 7, че ето за модель? это очень мало для андроид разработки, как минимум надо купить 5, а лучше 10 девайсов с разной частотой процессора, диагональю экрана и плотностью пиклесей, насчет последней прошивки - это неплохо, но пройдется купить еще пару девайсов со старой прошикой, что бы тестировать обратную совместимость и конечно надо купить кружку с андроидом, потому что сейчас неактуально программировать без такой кружки на столе... =(

Comment: про кружку хорошо, де её добыть?)
а по поводу других девайсов это конечно да но было бы круто если бы на планшете можно было реализовывать много операционность как на компе, это бы решило отчасти проблему с кучей девайсов со стороны версий операционной системы, но не железа,конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я себе планирую купить. Исходя из общих тенденций - все новое будет появляться именно в "устройствах от гугл".
Но для нормальной разработки нужно иметь хотя бы штук 5 девайсов разных видов и производителей. У меня, к примеру, есть три телефона и два планшета.

Comment: ого, и все на Android?Планшеты каких моделей?

Comment: Acer A500 и Nook Color (это не совсем планшет, но...)

Comment: Чем, на большем количестве устройств вы сможете проверить, тем лучше. Помню на хабре был пост о компании, которая проверяет свои андроид разработки на более 400 устройствах андроид.

Comment: А вот если брать в счет устройства, к которым я имею доступ (то есть, взять на полчаса поганять программу - не проблема) - это уже десятки устройств.

Comment: короче, я понял, у кого больше девайсов тот круче разработчик =) у меня например нету не одного адроид девайса, пойду я значит от сюда =)... и кружки даже нету =(

Comment: KoVadim, если писать только под планшет, то можно обойтись планшетом? Приложение по идее должно идти корректно на таких же 7 дюймовых экранах?

Comment: Если слишком не зарываться в апи и следить за его "чистотой", то с большой вероятностью все будет более-менее работать без проблем. На устройствах с других разрешением экрана нужно будет проверить, как будет выглядать. Возможно, нужно будет отдельные layout'ы сделать, графику дорисовать.

Comment: ага, спасибо, это учту))

Answer (score 2):

Как разработчик использовал по крайней мере 4 разных модели - никакой разницы не заметил. Берите что попроще и не забивайте себе голову крутизной. Главное чтобы:

1. У телефона была девелоперская мода (режим отладки)
2. Был нормальный драйвер USB под вашу операционку.

Comment: А ещё не известно есть ли в Google Nexus 7 всё это? Вроде на всех планшетах что под Android должны быть эти характеристики

Comment: Конечно есть, везде есть...

Comment: >> Был нормальный драйвер USB под вашу операционку.
тут забыли дописать "под вашу виндовс операционку". Под линуксом заводиться в 99% случаев сразу, в других - нужно добавить пару строк в конфиг, что бы операционка разрешила работать с этим устройством не только от рута (это больше зависит от версии системы и паранои ее создателей, чем  от самого устройства).

Comment: Исходя из всего, что поведали уделившие внимание данному вопросу люди, выходит что всё же Google Nexus 7, стоит таки брать,т.к. всё новенькое от создателей Android будет в ближайшие годы выходить под него,так же разрешение экрана у него такое, как у большего числа пользователей планшетов(в метро в основном люди с 7"дюймовыми), и в принципе, так как мир идёт на наращивание производительности, то и хорошо что там 4 ядра, а так же нужные дрова для работы с девайсом всега можно прогуглить "прогульщиком" или юзать LINUX, :-)